# Can you get holoviews renderer('bokeh').server_doc to work for Bars? NoneType/ColorConverter error

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, holoviews

This is interesting because I can get hv.Table to work, but hv.Bars is throwing the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/util.py", line 120, in mpl_to_bokeh
>   v = colors.ColorConverter.colors.get(v, v)
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ColorConverter'
>   and
>   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/holoviews/core/options.py", line 165, in **exit**
>   raise AbbreviatedException(etype, value, traceback)
>   holoviews.core.options.AbbreviatedException: AbbreviatedException: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ColorConverter'

The exception traces back to the following line in my code:
`graph = hv.renderer('bokeh').server_doc(df3)`

Details:

from requirements.txt:

> bokeh==0.12.6
>   holoviews==1.8.2

from app.py:

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
```

and

```
def graph_alpha(dataframe):
    # function to create a graph for the alpha cash flow dataframe
    df1=dataframe 
    df1['date'] = df1.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')

    k_dims = [('date','Date')]
    val_dims = [('netincome', 'EBITDA')]

    plot_opts = dict(fill_color='#00AA00')

    df2 = hv.Table(df1,kdims=k_dims, vdims=val_dims)
    df3 = hv.Bars(df1,kdims=k_dims, vdims=val_dims)
    #df3 = hv.Bars(df1,kdims=k_dims, vdims=val_dims).opts(plot=plot_opts)
    #df3 = hv.Bars(df2).opts(plot=plot_opts)
    #df3 = hv.Bars(df2).opts(style=plot_opts)
    graph = hv.renderer('bokeh').server_doc(df3)

    return graph
```

Any thoughts on this?

I looked through all the open and closed issues, and didn't see this one. 
Hope we can figure it out.

Chad

Answer (score 4):

Found out that there is a lingering/inadvertent dependency on matplotlib.

Installed matplotlib 2.0.2 and hv.Bars now works.

Thanks.